# How to get Xpath of sub menu?

Tags: selenium, automation

How to get Xpath of submenu when user click on main menu in selenium?

I have tried with finding ID and attribute name but its not working. 
Please help

Comment: Share more details: `HTML` of menu/submenu, code you've tried, error logs...

Comment: Can you show us some of your work please?

Comment: Share the HTML code or the xpath's you have tried till yet

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Firebug/Firepath add-ons if your using the Firefox browser to get the xpath values generated by the tools. If those don't work then share the HTML code for better clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your element of submenu is not visible at the current time when you are tried find it by `ID` or `Name`. You should to make click on `Menu` and only then try to find this element of submenu by `ID` or `Name` - it have to be visible.
If you will not find element of submenu this way, write here HTML-code of page and your selenium-script.